# What is the join between the neck and the chin called, is it called "the crook of the head"?

Tags: word-usage, word-request, phrase-usage, phrase-request

[image]

What is the join between the neck and the chin called as shown in the picture, is it called "**the crook of the head**"?

Comment: There is no single word for that. It is, as you say, the "junction of the neck and chin".

Comment: If there's any looseness, it could be called a jowl.

Answer (score 1):

The soft area between the hard edges of the chin bone and the throat proper might be described as 'under the chin'. I have never heard it called the crook of my head/neck.

A more accurate, medical term might be the digastric site, but that would not be understood in every day speech.